# MP4 video on window webserver not playing in quick time and flash player(flv player)

Tags: asp.net

I have two mp4 video files on webserver, i wanted to play them in flash player(flv player) on my asp.net page, but i couldn't be able to play them, i also tried to play them in quick time player the same prob occured. but i waz giving the accurate path, there were no spaces in mp4 file names etc.

Does it need to have mp4 player(or codec etc) installed on webserver?

I have also some wmv files on that server , and i am playing perfectly using silver light player, and media player object on my website.

So please share your knowledge... thanks in advance...

Comment: Please post some code and URLs you used. Also, are you using Flash 10?

Comment: actually i am using quick time player for mp4 files, like this: http://www.mediacollege.com/video/format/mpeg4/streaming/example.html But does it need to have any codec/software installed on win webserver? I m giving correct url...

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you set mimetype for mp4 video in web.config file.

```
<staticContent> 
 <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" /> 
</staticContent>
```